# Is there a classification code system for TB patients (registered for follow-up) in the West?

Tags: terminology, tuberculosis

I came across the following sentence in a Russian text:

> Диссеминированный туберкулез легких в фазе инфильтрации, МБТ (-) IА

I translated it as:

> Disseminated pulmonary tuberculosis at the infiltration stage, Mtb(-), **I-A**

The matter is, the **I-A** stands for Group 1 (confirmed active TB in this patient), subtype A (first occurrence of TB in this patient).

This is a [classification system](http://web-local.rudn.ru/web-local/uem/autor/koshechkin/tub_rus/tub2005_ru/08_org/08_3_disp_groups.htm) used in Russia for TB patients, who are required to register at a clinic in order to be tracked and cured. ("*Диспансерные группы больных туберкулезом*")

For instance, **1-Б** (Cyrillic for 1-B) would mean "Confirmed active TB in this patient; reccurrent case", and 2-B would mean "Chronically ill TB patient; uncurable case".

Is there a similar code system for classification of TB patients in the West?

If no, I'd probably have to write (Russian classification system) in parentheses after **I-A** to make it clearer to the reader. I found that in one Russian-to-English translation [they explain](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/management-of-the-hiv-positive-pregnant-patient-with-marked-immunodeficiency-and-multiple-comorbidities) the thing as "dispensary registry group":

> [image]

"Dispensary" is a crude direct translation of Russian "Диспансер" (Dispanser), a treatment center specializing on this or that disease.